# Restore/Rollback Azure Website

Tags: azure, cloud, backup, restore, rollback

I have **not** used any Source control mechanism (`TFS` or `GIT`) to deploy my Umbraco app to `Azure WebSites`. Also I don't have any backups of the WebSite(Backups created on Azure Management portal). Also I don't have a previous version of the whole project with me locally. Is there any way I can restore or backup my Azure Website to previous deployment ? Or is it completely impossible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to restore it the way you have described your situation.